# Domain of function 1.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

what is the domain of $$f(x)=\ln(\sin x)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $\ln$ is the napierian logarithm. Thanks.

Comment: You need $\sin x > 0$ so what can you say about $x$?

Comment: $x\in(2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi)$ for all $n$

Comment: Tanks @ Dr. MV but If if we  put $n=1$, then $x\in(2\pi,3\pi)$ in this case $\sin (3\pi/2)=-1<0$

Comment: $3/2 \in (2,3)$?

Comment: No (sorry). tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ln is defined for all positive numbers, so when is sin(x) positive?